# How to process text elements correctly with iterparse() in LXML?

Tags: xml, python-3.x, lxml, sax

Here is a simple XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
  <someThing>
    Text A: This is a test line.
    <p>Some paragraph.</p>
    Text B: This is another test line.
    <p>Some other paragraph.</p>
    Text C: And even another test line.
  </someThing>
</root>
```

Though the test XML file is very small the actual file I would like to process is fairly large: A few gigabytes. I therefor would like to parse this file using iterparse() using the following Python code.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
FILE_NAME = "test.xml"
for event, element in etree.iterparse(FILE_NAME, events=("start", "end", "start-ns", "end-ns")):
        print(event, "\t", element, "\t", repr(element.text))
```

If I run this I get the following output:

```
start    <Element 'root' at 0x7fd96a6aa728>      '\n\t'
start    <Element 'someThing' at 0x7fd968fba688>     '\n\t\tText A: This is a test line.\n\t\t'
start    <Element 'p' at 0x7fd968fcaf48>     'Some paragraph.'
end      <Element 'p' at 0x7fd968fcaf48>     'Some paragraph.'
start    <Element 'p' at 0x7fd968fcaf98>     'Some other paragraph.'
end      <Element 'p' at 0x7fd968fcaf98>     'Some other paragraph.'
end      <Element 'someThing' at 0x7fd968fba688>     '\n\t\tText A: This is a test line.\n\t\t'
end      <Element 'root' at 0x7fd96a6aa728>      '\n\t'
```

As you can see the text elements after the `<p>`-elements are ignored.

My question is: How do I need to use the LXML API to process the contents of this file correctly? All examples I could find until now about that topic don't do anything different than my short piece of code and therefor suffer from the same problem. If the case this can not be done with LXML does anybody know of a different XML parser I could use and provide a short example?

Comment: The missing text pieces are found in the `tail` of the `<p>` elements. This is a peculiarity of ElementTree and lxml. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail, and http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pylxml/web/etree-view.html.

Comment: Very strange - but thank you for this information! That was something I was initially looking for. Nevertheless using SAX directly seems to be the cleaner solution: I have about one million entries nested in a single element which I can not prevent the etree API from collecting. And etree uses SAX under the hood anyway.

Answer (score 0):

According to the kind comment of user `mzjn` you could do it with LXML: There is a `tail` attribute the missing text is appended to. But likely this isn't not the best way to do it because of the following reasons:

- LXML will inevitably construct a large tree (which partially can be truncated manually of course during processing the events, but this is far from optimal)
- There is no clean single event for parsing the text between two elements so you will have to work around this by parsing `tail`.

Alternative solution: Do it with the SAX API directly.

Example:

```
import xml.sax

FILE_NAME = "test.xml"

class MyHandler(xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler):

    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        print("startElement\t" + repr(name))

    def endElement(self, name):
        print("endElement\t" + repr(name))

    def startElementNS(self, name, qname, attrs):
        print("startElementNS\t" + repr(name))

    def endElementNS(self, name, qname):
        print("endElementNS\t" + repr(name))

    def characters(self, content):
        print("  chars\t\t" + repr(content))

contentHandler = MyHandler()
xml.sax.parse(FILE_NAME, contentHandler)
```

This example above will be a good starting point processing huge XML files. The method `characters()` will get invoked for every piece of text parsed. Entities are decoded and cause a call to `characters()` as well so it's easy to collect all text stored at a XML element. If you implement a simple stack that grows and shrinks on calls to `startElement()` and `endElement()` in your content handler you can easily parse specific parts of a tree and leave out what you don't need to process.